# Creating equivalent Rails workspaces on a Mac and a Linux box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, macos, vim, terminal

I'm happy using TextMate and Terminal to develop in Ruby on Rail on Mac OS X.

I like being able to drag windows to resize them. I like having access to standard Mac shortcuts like command-X, etc. I like having the same look and feel as my other apps.

They both flow much more naturally than, say, PowerShell and Edit++ on Windows, which is why I've largely steered clear of using my Intel laptop for Rails.

But now I'm going to have to start swapping back and forth between my Mac and the Intel laptop so I'm thinking of installing Linux on the latter.

My question is in two parts:

(1) Can I install a terminal app and a text editor on Linux that flows just as naturally as TextMate and Terminal does on Mac OS X? Preferably, I'd want the same shortcuts etc on both platforms. (Except that the command key obviously gets mapped to control or whatever.)

(2) Failing that, I might move to a more Linux-like way of working on the Mac to create a situation where I'm working in the same way on both machines. To do this, is there an equivalent of MacVim on Linux, or should I just move to Vim on the Mac? What would be the parallel set-up (inc terminal app) on Linux?

Comment: I moved from TextMate to VIM for precisely this reason. After a few months of cutting my teeth on it - I can confirm the zeitgeist - I prefer VIM and am now equally as efficient on Linux or OS X...

Comment: Cheers. Vim or MacVim? On what Linux distro? And with what Linux terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Aptana Studio 3, if you dare to switch to a full blown IDE.

(1) Aptana has a built in Terminal. Flowing as naturally as Terminal and TextMate? probably not.

(2) Aptana works on Linux, OS X and Windows, so everything should be the same.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'm happier with a text editor and terminal than with an IDE.

Comment: I just got advertising for redcareditor.com, seems to be exactly what ur looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you plan to use your linux distro with gnome instead of kde, you probably should check gedit with gmate plugins, although is not like textmate power, it has a lot of it features. Another thing is that mac comes with zsh, so ur linux distro can also be installed with zsh and tuned to work with it, instead of the default gnome-terminal terminal.